# download python library to create deployment package

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying to download a python library (requests) into a folder in order to create a deployment package.

from terminal (I am on mac)

i use

```
pip3 install requests -t .
```

I get the following error.

```
Collecting requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/da/55f51ea951e1b7c63a579c09dd7db825bb730ec1fe9c0180fc77bfb31448/urllib3-1.25.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.wh
➜  AWS apt-get install python3-pip
zsh: command not found: apt-get
➜  AWS ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip3
ln: /usr/bin/pip3: Operation not permitted
➜  AWS ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3
ln: /usr/local/bin/pip3: File exists
➜  AWS pip3 install requests -t .                                                         
Collecting requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none
-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-a
ny.whl
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.wh
l
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/da/55f51ea951e1b7c63a579c09dd7db825bb730ec1fe9c0180fc77bfb31448/urllib3-1.25.6-py2.py3-none-
any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/b0/8146a4f8dd402f60744fa380bc73ca47303cccf8b9190fd16a827281eac2/certifi-2019.9.11-py2.py3-no
ne-any.whl
Installing collected packages: chardet, idna, urllib3, certifi, requests
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 393, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 57, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 913, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 445, in move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 313, in move_wheel_files
    prefix=prefix,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 180, in distutils_scheme
    i.finalize_options()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 248, in finalize_options
    "must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both")
distutils.errors.DistutilsOptionError: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both
```

any idea how to fix this?

the requests packages in already installed and I have made a test script that uses it and it works.

I just would like to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by running

pip3 install -U pip

and then re-runnig

pip3 install requests -t .

Comment: Pipe should be pip in the above command.  Also, is this for lambda because you can access requests also with: from botocore.vendored import requests